# WHERE clause for day only in a datetime field MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a query to return all results where my datetime field has a day of '14'.  How can I do this please?  I am using MySQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in function for that called [DAYOFMONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth)

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName 
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(dateColumn) = 14
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2536/1)

SOURCE

- [DAYOFMONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth)

Answer (score 3):

you can use [**EXTRACT ()**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_extract.asp) function in mysql to extract the day from a given date

```
select * 
from your_table
where EXTRACT(DAY FROM Date_col)=14
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79433/1)